# How to write an AJAX call to get an XML file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I need to write a web page with a button “Get Flight Information”. When the user clicks this button, write an AJAX call to get the XML file that you wrote in Question 1, parse the XML into a Javascript object, and then display the Javascript object on the web page exactly as
follows:
[image]

Here is my code so far. I am extremely new to this so please go easy guys! :

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flightInfo>
<Date>02OCT19</Date>
<Flight> VA 1429 </Flight>
<Depart>Sydney</Depart>
<Arrive>Cairns</Arrive>
<Boarding>Gate 35 At 1855</Boarding>
<Carrier>Virgin Australia</Carrier>
</flightInfo>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get flight 
information</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "Question1.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Depart</th><th>Arrive</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("Depart")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("Arrive")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("Date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't load a file from the file system this way, it would be really insecure if a browser let you do that.  You might want to use a web server like nodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get flight 
information</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "Question1.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table=`<tr><th>Depart</th><th>Arrive</th></tr>`;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += `<tr><td>` +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("Depart")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    `</td><td>` +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("Arrive")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    `</td><td>` +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("Date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    `</td></tr>`;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think this should help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){


 var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><flightInfo><Date>02OCT19</Date><Flight> VA 1429 </Flight><Depart>Sydney</Depart><Arrive>Cairns</Arrive><Boarding>Gate 35 At 1855</Boarding><Carrier>Virgin Australia</Carrier></flightInfo>'   
    
//Parse the givn XML
var xmlDoc1 = $.parseXML( data ); 
    
var $xml1 = $(xmlDoc1);

  // Find Person Tag
var $flightInfo = $xml1.find("flightInfo");


$flightInfo.each(function(){
   
    var Date = $(this).find('Date').text(),
        Depart = $(this).find('Depart').text(),
        Arrive = $(this).find('Arrive').text() ;
    
    $("#data" ).append('<li>' + Date + ' - ' + Depart+  ' - ' + Arrive + '</li>');
    
});
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="data"></ul>
```

first of all you need to parse your data in xml object as below after that you can read it.
try below solution.

```
<ul id="data"></ul>
<script>
$(function(){


 var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><flightInfo><Date>02OCT19</Date><Flight> VA 1429 </Flight><Depart>Sydney</Depart><Arrive>Cairns</Arrive><Boarding>Gate 35 At 1855</Boarding><Carrier>Virgin Australia</Carrier></flightInfo>'   

//Parse the givn XML
var xmlDoc1 = $.parseXML( data ); 

var $xml1 = $(xmlDoc1);

  // Find Person Tag
var $flightInfo = $xml1.find("flightInfo");


$flightInfo.each(function(){

    var Date = $(this).find('Date').text(),
        Depart = $(this).find('Depart').text(),
        Arrive = $(this).find('Arrive').text() ;

    $("#data" ).append('<li>' + Date + ' - ' + Depart+  ' - ' + Arrive + '</li>');

});

});
</script>
```

check live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ru92p4en/